# WPF ListBox doesn't show any content

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I've got a problem with ListBox. I'm trying to populate it with data from database, but the listbox doesn't show. I've looked through many similar questions, but didn't find any answer that would work for me :(
My code for ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="OrdersListBox" Grid.Row="1"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OrdersTemplate}">
</ListBox>
```

And for OrdersTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OrdersTemplate">
                <StackPanel>
                    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" DataContext="{StaticResource OrdersViewSource}">
                        <TextBlock Text="OrderID: " FontSize="18"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderID}" FontSize="18"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Code for Page:

```
    public partial class Account : Page
    {
        Entities1 Context;
        Customers Customer;
        CollectionViewSource OrdersViewSource;
        public Account(Entities1 Context, Customers Customer)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Context = Context;
            this.Customer = Customer;
            this.OrdersViewSource = this.FindResource("OrdersViewSource") as CollectionViewSource;
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Context.Orders.Load();
            this.OrdersViewSource.Source = Context.Orders.Local.Where(o => o.CustomerName == Customer.CompanyName).Select(o => o);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Orders Order = new Orders
            {
                CustomerName = Customer.CompanyName
            };
            NewOrder NewOrder = new NewOrder(Context, Order);
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(NewOrder);

        }
    }
```

I've got also this in Grid.Resources:

```
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="OrdersViewSource"/>
```

I'm pretty sure that binding works, 'cause when calling ListBox this way:

```
<ListBox x:Name="OrdersListBox" Grid.Row="1"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OrdersTemplate}">
                <DockPanel/>
            </ListBox>
```

it shows the first OrderID element.

Why can't I see any ListBox when running my app?

Comment: Which "binding works"? You don't seem to set the ListBox's ItemsSource anywhere.

Comment: I've had this code: ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource OrdersViewSource}}", but read somewhere that i shouldn't use both ItemsSource and DataContext (which I have in DockPanel) and deleted it. However, it didn't work with ItemsSource, and I got binding errors when I didn't have DataContext id DockPanel

Comment: Without setting either the ItemsSource property or adding objects to the Items property, a ListBox won't show anything. The DataContext is typically not set explicitly, but only inherited from the Window, in order to provide a view model object with the source properties for Bindings.

Comment: @Clemens but even after setting ItemsSource I still get no data in ListBox. Do you have any idea why it happens?

Comment: Not without further information. We don't know anything about the rest of your code. Please share the relevant parts, especially the view model declarations.

Comment: @Clemens I added relevant parts of my code, thank you for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok what you have done is that you bound your `ItemTemplate` to the resource you wanted. Which should be `ItemsSource` instead.
When you added an item manually the list tried to render your item using the template that you provided which is your actual data.

You might want to do something like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="OrdersListBox" Grid.Row="1" 
         VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource OrdersTemplate}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource OrdersViewSource}}">
</ListBox>
```

And then remove the data binding on the template like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OrdersTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="OrderID: " FontSize="18"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderID}" FontSize="18"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I'm not sure of this works because I don't know that if the data in `OrdersViewSource` is the actual items that you want to show in the list but you get the idea.

You need an array of items assigned to the `ItemsSource` property of the list.

Comment: I've had it before and it also didn't show any content :( tried one more time right now, still no data

Comment: Use `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource OrdersViewSource}}"` in case OrdersViewSource is a CollectionViewSource resource. `ItemsSource="{StaticResource OrdersViewSource}"` won't work.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks man. My WPF has gotten a little rusty these days.

Comment: @Emilianna Would you please tell me that what is type of `OrdersViewSource` and where are the items you want to show in the list

Comment: OrdersViewSource is a CollectionViewSource, I want to show OrderIDs from this View that I populated with data using select from database (Customer is a field in my Page class): this.OrdersViewSource.Source = Context.Orders.Local.Where(o => o.CustomerName == Customer.CompanyName).Select(o => o);

Comment: This should work. Can you please remove the `DockPanel` from the template and just keep the texts. See if this shows the items.

Comment: DockPanel removed, still no items :(